Alternative approach for $\int\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\csc^{-1} (x)\right) - \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}(x)\right)} \, dx$
This is example 2 in my "Integration Using Some Euler-Like Identities" blog post.
$$\int\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\csc^{-1} (x)\right) - \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}(x)\right)} \, dx\tag{1}$$
Wolfram Alpha is unable to simplify and solve it by itself. By applying the following general transformation formula:
$$\int f\left(x,\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}, \tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}} \right)\,dx=\int f\left(\frac{e^{i\alpha}+e^{-i\alpha}}{2}a, e^{i\alpha}, \frac{1-e^{i\alpha}}{1+e^{i\alpha}}\right)\,\frac{e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha}}{2i}a\,d\alpha,\tag{2}$$
where $\alpha=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$, $\beta=\csc^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$ and $\gamma=\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$, the integral $(1)$ becomes
$$=-\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{e^{-i\alpha} - e^{i\alpha} - e^{2i\alpha} + 1}{e^{2i\alpha}+2e^{i\alpha}-1}\,d\alpha.$$
Then, let $u=e^{i\alpha}\implies du=ie^{i\alpha}\,d\alpha$. Then, putting terms over a common denominator, and factoring, we have
$$-\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{e^{-i\alpha} - e^{i\alpha} - e^{2i\alpha} + 1}{e^{2i\alpha}+2e^{i\alpha}-1}\,d\alpha=\frac12\int\frac{(u - 1) (u + 1)^2}{u^2 (u^2 + 2 u - 1)}\,du$$
At this point, we can proceed by applying partial fraction decomposition.
What other method do you have in mind to solve $(1)$?
This is what WA returns:


Note that
$$\tan(\frac12\sec^{-1}x)= \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}},>>>>>
\tan(\frac12\csc^{-1}x)= x-\sqrt{x^2-1} $$

Wolfram can actually finish the integral, see here. The problem is that it didn't understand your input - in general try not to use decimals (e.g. replace $0.5$ with $\frac12$).
To do it manually I'd probably rewrite the integral as: $$\int\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}-\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}}dx\overset{\frac{x-1}{x+1}=t^2}=4\int\frac{t}{(1+t)(1-t)^2(1-2t-t^2)}dt$$
Which should be straightforward. Also, an alternative substitution that can be used there is $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}=t$.

@Zacky: But when I access your WA link, it also doesn't resolve (it says it times out). Are you using the PRO version?

@EmmanuelJoséGarcía that's weird.. I don't have any PRO version, here's what I see: https://i.sstatic.net/AJO2fai8.png

@Zacky: I have edited my question so that you can see what I see from your WA link.

Apparently I also get timed out if I run it in the Spanish language, however, in English it seems to work perfectly.

@Zacky: It works in English. That's weird indeed!

Even more weird is that in Spanish it can evaluate $\int \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\csc^{-1} (x)\right) dx$ and  $\int \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1} (x)\right) dx$  separately - so it's not a language barrier problem.

@Zacky: However, WA (in English) is unable to compute this integral: $$\int  \frac{{1 - \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}{{1 + \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}\sqrt{\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}{2}},dx.$$ The transformation $(2)$, however, makes it child's play.

@EmmanuelJoséGarcía Yes, the substitution is good - it also seems that wolfram struggles with such integrals. An alternative is the substitution I mentioned above: $\frac{x-1}{x+1}=t^2$, which gives: $$\int\frac{{1 - \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}{{1 + \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}\sqrt{\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}{2}} dx\overset{\large \frac{x-1}{x+1}=t^2}=4\int \frac{t}{(1+t)^3\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\overset{\large \frac{1-t}{1+t}=y^2}= \int(y^4-1)dy$$

@Zacky: Apparently, my method leads to a simpler partial fraction decomposition for the original integral. Compare the systems of equations (see here and here). It would be interesting to investigate if this technique is optimal for this type of integrals.

Now, for some strange reason, WA is unable to solve the integral from my original question even when using English.
